# JSON para websocket dá erro

Tags: javascript, c#, json, api, websocket

Eu envio um JSON para o websocket. O JSON e o envio está definido assim:

```
var binary = btoa(Uint8ToString(view));

var toSend = {

  'fileName': fileName,
  'sequence': SendedChunks,
  'data': binary.toString()

};


var z = JSON.stringify(toSend);

socket.send(z);
```

Nos parâmetros temos o nome do ficheiro (cada ficheiro tem N linhas json), a sua sequência (como o mesmo ficheiro tem N jsons, precisamos de reconstruir pela ordem correta) e data, que contêm os dados obtidos da webcam (video+áudio).

Esta parte funciona tudo bem, porém quando chega ao backend o json não é descodificado como deve ser...as vezes a string com o json não fecha (não tem chaveta no final) outras parece que não vem aberto (não começa com as chavetas e os parâmetros, vem só a parte final)...não sei o que fazer visto que alguns jsons são processados corretamente, mas depois de enviar umas quantas vezes ele começa a estragar o json.

O que poderá ser? no backend trato assim o json enviado pelo código que escrevi anteriormente:

```
byte[] payloadData = receiveBuffer.Array.Where(b => b != 0).ToArray();

//Because we know that is a string, we convert it. 
string receiveString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(payloadData, 0, payloadData.Length);
dynamic receivedObj = Json.Decode < dynamic > (receiveString); //AQUI DÁ ERRO
TransFile transFileChunk = new TransFile();

string Key = receivedObj["fileName"];
transFileChunk.sequence = receivedObj["sequence"];

string ba = receivedObj["data"];
transFileChunk.bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ba);
```